# Ubuntu OS Query for old OS

Tags: desktop-environments

I have an old desktop with 2GB of RAM and an Intel Pentium 32-bit CPU.

Which version of Ubuntu should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Lubuntu 14.04, unless you have a decent graphics card, in which case you could run the regular version.